# ActiveDocument.Tables.Count returns 0 but there are 4 tables

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

Issue Resolved: I had two different sessions of word running. The code was in one but the tables were in the other.

---

There are 4 tables in the document but ActiveDocument.Tables.Count isn't working. Any ideas?

[image: Two of tables in document.]

Comment: Are those actual tables?  Do they give the `Table` menu in the Ribbon when you click in them?  Do they give the crosshairs in the corner when you hover on them?  You can do a lot with borders and columns to deceive someone.  Also is `ActiveDocument` what you think it is?  You can do `?ActiveDocument.Name` in the immediate window to test.

Comment: I came back to answer and you're right. I guess I had two different sessions of word running. The code was in one but the tables were in the other. I'll keep that ActiveDocument.Name test handy in the future. That was it. Thanks!

Comment: Add your resolution as an actual answer below and accept.

Answer (score 0):

I had two different sessions of word running. The code was in one but the tables were in the other.